# Filling the space between two rectangles

Tags: c#, gdi+

how would I go about filling the space between two rectangles when they are not vertically aligned. So if one rectangle moves up the gap between it and the next rectangle (In a chain which all follow the same path) looks smooth.

Example:

Current:
[image: Ugly gap]

Desired:
[image: Desired look]

My current drawing code:

```
public override void Draw(Graphics g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this._Children.Count; i++)
    {
        this._Children[i].Draw(g);

        if (i != 0 && i + 1 < this._Children.Count)
        {
            if (this._Children[i].Y != this._Children[i + 1].Y)
            {
                 //Draw circle in gap between?
            }
        }
    }

    base.Draw(g);
}
```

Underlying draw:

```
g.FillRectangle(this.Color, this.X, this.Y, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
g.DrawRectangle(this.Outline, this.X, this.Y, this.Size.Width, this.Size.Height);
```

Edit:

After following Jim and commenter's advice, I came up with the following. The maths seems to be wrong and it doesn't really get the effect I wanted at all though.

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

for (int i = 0; i < this._Children.Count; i++)
{
    path.AddRectangle(this._Children[i].GetBoundingBox());

    if (i < this._Children.Count)
    {
        Block block = i == 0 ? (Block)this : this._Children[i - 1];

        float x = this._Children[i].X < block.X ? this._Children[i].X : block.X;
        float y = this._Children[i].Y > block.X ? this._Children[i].Y : block.Y;
        float width = System.Math.Abs(this._Children[i].X - block.X);
        float height = System.Math.Abs(this._Children[i].Y - block.Y);
        path.AddEllipse(x, y, width, height);
    }
}

g.FillPath(this._Children[0].Color, path);
g.DrawPath(this._Children[0].Outline, path);
base.Draw(g);
```

[image]

Edit 2: Been following everyone's advice and editing as I go along. Jim's works now but it only draws at all if you are moving up and you start moving right.

And now with TAW's advice I get ArguementInvalid, I assume this is because the rGap rectangle's height is 0.

My implementation of TAW's:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this._Children.Count; i++)
{
    this._Children[i].Draw(g);

    if (i + 1 < this._Children.Count)
    {
        Block block = i == 0 ? (Block)this : this._Children[i + 1];

        Rectangle rec = this._Children[i].GetBoundingBox();
        Rectangle rec2 = block.GetBoundingBox();
        Rectangle rGap = new Rectangle(Math.Min(rec.X, rec2.X), Math.Min(rec.Y, rec2.Y), 2 * Math.Abs(rec.Left - rec2.Left), 2 * Math.Abs(rec2.Top - rec.Top));

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath();
        gp.AddRectangle(rec);
        gp.AddRectangle(rec2);
        gp.AddArc(rGap, 0, 360);

        gp.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;
        g.DrawPath(this._Children[i].Outline, gp);
        g.FillPath(this._Children[i].Color, gp);
    }
}

base.Draw(g);
```

Edit 3:
I have developed my own solution after studying the problem a little more, it's not the solution I wanted but hopefully it should help someone else. Now it just needs converting to rounded corners.

Code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < this._Children.Count; i++)
{
    this._Children[i].Draw(g);

    Block block = i - 1 < 0 ? (Block)this : this._Children[i - 1];

    Rectangle rec = this._Children[i].GetBoundingBox();
    Rectangle rec2 = block.GetBoundingBox();
    Direction dir = this._Children[i].GetDirection(true);
    Direction dir2 = block.GetDirection(true);

    int minX = Math.Min(rec.X, rec2.X);
    int minY = Math.Min(rec.Y, rec2.Y);
    int maxX = Math.Max(rec.X, rec2.X);
    int maxY = Math.Max(rec.Y, rec2.Y);
    int diffX = maxX - minX;
    int diffY = maxY - minY;
    int width = this._Children[i].Size.Width;
    int height = this._Children[i].Size.Height;
    Rectangle fillRec = default(Rectangle);

    if ((dir == Direction.Right && dir2 == Direction.Down) || (dir == Direction.Up && dir2 == Direction.Left))
    {
        fillRec = new Rectangle(minX + width, minY, diffX, diffY);
    }
    else if ((dir == Direction.Down && dir2 == Direction.Left) || (dir == Direction.Right && dir2 == Direction.Up))
    {
        fillRec = new Rectangle(minX + width, (maxY + height) - diffY, diffX, diffY);
    }
    else if ((dir == Direction.Up && dir2 == Direction.Right) || (dir == Direction.Left && dir2 == Direction.Down))
    {
        fillRec = new Rectangle(minX, minY, diffX, diffY);
    }
    else if ((dir == Direction.Left && dir2 == Direction.Up) || (dir == Direction.Down && dir2 == Direction.Right))
    {
        fillRec = new Rectangle(minX, (maxY + height) - diffY, diffX, diffY);
    }

    if (fillRec != default(Rectangle))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(this._Children[i].Color, fillRec);
        g.DrawRectangle(this._Children[i].Outline, fillRec);
    }
}
base.Draw(g);
```

Produces: [image]

Comment: You'll want to use a GraphicsPath object.

Comment: I converted it to graphics path, but how do I fill in the gap still?

Comment: You can add a circle to the path and fill it and draw its outline

Comment: I've done that, it has not solved it, my maths must be wrong (Went off what Jim said) because when going up or right it works fine but when going down or left it draws on the wrong side. Also it doesn't give the desired effect but rather fill some of the space. Updated OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that draws all four rounded corneres for four rectangles.

I create four rectangles overlapping with various gaps and add them and the arcs to fill the gaps to a GraphicsPath.

```
GraphicsPath GP = new GraphicsPath();

Rectangle fillGap(Rectangle R1, Rectangle R2, bool isTop, bool isLeft )
{ 
    int LeftMin    = Math.Min(R1.Left, R2.Left);
    int RightMax   = Math.Max(R1.Right, R2.Right);
    int TopMin     = Math.Min(R1.Top, R2.Top);
    int BotMax     = Math.Max(R1.Bottom, R2.Bottom);
    int RightGap   = 2 * Math.Abs(R1.Right - R2.Right);
    int LeftGap    = 2 * Math.Abs(R1.Left - R2.Left);
    int TopGap     = 2 * Math.Abs(R1.Top - R2.Top);
    int BotGap     = 2 * Math.Abs(R1.Bottom - R2.Bottom);

    Rectangle R = Rectangle.Empty; 
    if (isTop && isLeft) R = new Rectangle(LeftMin, TopMin, LeftGap, TopGap);
    if (isTop && !isLeft) 
        R = new Rectangle(RightMax - RightGap, TopMin, RightGap, TopGap);
    if (!isTop && !isLeft) 
        R = new Rectangle(RightMax - RightGap, BotMax  - BotGap , RightGap, BotGap );
    if (!isTop && isLeft) 
        R = new Rectangle(LeftMin, BotMax  - BotGap , LeftGap, BotGap );
     return R;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle Rtop = new Rectangle(20, 10, 200, 40);
    Rectangle Rbottom = new Rectangle(20, 200, 200, 40);
    Rectangle Rleft = new Rectangle(10, 20, 40, 200);
    Rectangle Rright = new Rectangle(210, 20, 40, 200);

    GP = new GraphicsPath(); 
    GP.FillMode = FillMode.Winding;

    GP.AddRectangle(Rtop);
    GP.AddRectangle(Rleft);
    GP.AddRectangle(Rbottom);
    GP.AddRectangle(Rright);
    GP.AddArc(fillGap(Rtop, Rleft, true, true), 0, 360);
    GP.AddArc(fillGap(Rtop, Rright, true, false), 0, 360);
    GP.AddArc(fillGap(Rbottom, Rleft, false, true), 0, 360);
    GP.AddArc(fillGap(Rbottom, Rright, false, false), 0, 360);

    panel1.Invalidate();
}

private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1.5f))
    {
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(pen, GP);
        if(checkBox1.Checked) e.Graphics.FillPath(Brushes.Red, GP);
    }
}
```

The code now assumes that your gaps are not wider than the rectanlges.

The Pen for the outline should not be smaller that 1.5f or the filling will overlap too much.

Also the Smoothing mode should be high quality, so no pixels get lost.

Here is how it looks : Drawn & filled:

[image: drawn][image: filled]

Comment: The rectangles all move at a fixed pace so they all move at the same time, but in the time when one rectangle is moving up to its next destination the next rectangle (its child) has to move to the x position before it can start going up. Essentially the time in which a shape changes movement direction causes a gap between two shapes, which is what I want to fill. I will play around with that code shortly, thanks for your help! :D

Comment: please see the changed code, should be much more helpful now.

Comment: How would I do the other corners? Edit: Yeah I copied the code and the circles are huge, about 5x the size of the rectangles.

Comment: I have corrected the code once more; I'll add the other corners tomoroow - we have a heat wavt that is getting to me..

Comment: See my simlipfied solution!

Comment: It's throwing argument exception because rGap height is 0.

rGap {X = 249 Y = 272 Width = 64 Height = 0}
 
rec {X = 249 Y = 272 Width = 32 Height = 32}

rec2 {X = 281 Y = 272 Width = 32 Height = 32}

Comment: Yes, you can't have a Shape with either height or width=0; since your rex1&2 sit on the same y position (272) the gap is zero. For these cases you don't actually need the whole gap-filling, right? You'll have to check rGap.Height*rGap.Width!=0 and skip the filling routine!

Comment: Okay I fixed that, but this still only works when you're going up and you start going right, otherwise it draws on the wrong side. IE: It is moving down and it turns right, it draws on the inside corner not the outside

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57603/discussion-between-user1763295-and-taw).

Answer (score 2):

You can't necessarily draw a circle in the space unless the space is square. But you can draw an ellipse.

What you need to do:

1. Determine extents of the rectangle in question. The center point is the point where the two rectangles meet (the bottom right part of the blank space you want to fill. The top left is the X coordinate of the left rectangle and the Y coordinate of the top rectangle. The width would be `2*(center.X - left)` and the height would be `2*(center.Y - top)`.
2. [Fill an ellipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.FillEllipse(v=vs.110).aspx) in that rectangle.

Note that the above will have the effect of drawing the top-left curved portion. It won't fully fill the overlapping rectangle below.

If you want to get rid of the lines, draw a filled rectangle without a border (actually, with the border the same color as the fill color) in the overlapping space. Then draw the filled ellipse as described above, again without a border.

To draw the border of the ellipse, look into [DrawArc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawArc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: See post update, I seem to have screwed it up. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @user1763295: My mistake. I believe you want the center point to be where the two rectangles meet, and make it twice the size. Draw the ellipse in there. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for updating. Just a bit confused on how I calculate the centre?

Comment: @user1763295: The center point is `(topRectangle.left, leftRectangle.top)`.

Comment: I have implemented this but it only draws correctly when you start going right when you were going up.

Comment: @user1763295: That's true. Generalizing it for all four corners shouldn't be terribly difficult.